# For a given real square matrix $A$ what is meant by $e^{kA}$ where $k$ is real.

Tags: linear-algebra

For a given real square matrix $A$ what is meant by $e^{kA}$ where $k$ is real?

I've problem involving this notion and I wondered if $e^{kA}=(e^{ka_{ij}})$ where $A=(a_{ij}).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the matrix exponential. By definition,

$$e^A = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^i}{i!}.$$

In your case, the matrix we're exponentiating is $kA$.

Your "intuition" that this can be computed component-wise is generally only true for the diagonal entries of diagonal matrices.

Comment: Even for diagonal matrices, naive component-wise exponentiation is wrong (it shouldn't be applied to off-diagonal entries).

Comment: @ErickWong Oh, yes, thank you.

Comment: To see some of the things that can go wrong, see the (wonderfully named) [Nineteen Dubious Ways to Compute the Exponential of a Matrix](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf).